# Update startTime of SQL table

Tags: sql, timestamp

I'm trying to update the StartTime of a table, but I get an error for the date format.
I don't want to use current_timestamp, but the specific date

```
SELECT * FROM [Carwash].[agents]
order by number 

UPDATE [agents]
  SET StartTime = "2020-06-03 15:32:05.000"
  WHERE number=456;
```

Suggestions?

Comment: tag your database

Comment: *I get an error* - always useful to include the actual error.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near "2020-06-03 15:32:05.000" was the error

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
  UPDATE [agents]
  SET StartTime = CONVERT( DATETIME, '2020-06-03 15:32:05.000', 121)
  Where number=456;
```